# How long NSThread instance live?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsthread

I am just wondering, I have following situation: I have NSOperationQueue which does some background calculations in few steps. It is obvious that it creates an instance of NSThread to do it in background. My question is how long does NSThread instance live? I am asking because from my experience it looks that thread lives even up to half a minute after NSOperationQueue is done with its job. Another question is, can I determine somehow the exact moment of thread termination?

Comment: You can use selectors to mark the time when the thread starts and terminates

Comment: Ok, that sound interesting. How and where should I put them?